# What are the pros and cons of HTTP callbacks vs. message passing?

Tags: callback, publish-subscribe, message-passing

We are looking to develop a number of services, but are not sure which "response" mechanism is the best route to go. The two contenders are:

1. **HTTP callbacks**, where the service would update the client application via "pinging" it with update messages sent via HTTP requests
2. **Message Passing**, where the service would update the client via publishing messages into a pub-sub queue on a message server

In both cases, both the caller and the services are within our network, we have full control over them, and things we develop are the only users of the services.

*What are the pros / cons of each way of providing status updates to the calling application, and what, if any, pros / cons would there be for making the initial request via one method or the other?*

<sub>Note: The first service we have in mind for this is an email service similar to SendGrid, which we can't use for various reasons, but still need the same functionality.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The main difference would be the quality of service that you get "out of the box" with a messaging server.

If you go with HTTP then your application has to take care of what happens when a message doesn't arrive as expected. To get an idea of the issues you need to consider and the complexities involved in solving them, take a look at [WS-ReliableMessaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-ReliableMessaging) or [HTTPLR](http://www.dehora.net/doc/httplr/draft-httplr-01.html).

With messaging, you get a configurable level of reliability out of the box. And there's a lot of good choice these days such as ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, 0MQ.

My personal preference is for reliability to be handled at the transport layer (by messaging), but then for a good discussion and dissenting view, check out "[Nobody Needs Reliable Messaging.](http://www.infoq.com/articles/no-reliable-messaging)"